# If statement inside Coroutine how it works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

1. in this example is this Coroutine will keep running without stopping or no ?
2. how many times "test-1" will be printed ?

Code-1:

```
bool a = true; 
bool b = true;

public IEnumerator ExampleCoroutine(){
    while (a){
        if(b){
            Debug.Log("test-1");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            Debug.Log("test-2");
         }
         Debug.Log("test-3");
         yield break;
     }
}
```

Comment: When you ran the code what happened?  Did it keep running, or did it stop?  How many times did it print "test-1"?

Comment: `how many times "test-1" will be printed ?` Whenever your question can be answered by **running the code**, consider carefully whether you should ask that question of others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## So, here's what happens:

I'm going to break down the code in your post one line at a time:

1. `while (a){`

   - If `a` is false, the coroutine exits immediately (go to 9) and nothing else happens, otherwise, continue
2. `if(b){`

   - if `b` is false, goto 7, otherwise, continue
3. `Debug.Log("test-1");`

   - print "test-1" to the console
4. `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);`

   - Here we create an object that when it is returned to the Unity system that handles coroutines (ie. `StartCoroutine()`) the execution of this function will be suspended and returned to at a later time. In this case, 1 second later (where this value is modified by the current `Time.timeScale`). When execution resumes, go to next step:
5. `Debug.Log("test-2");`

   - print "test-2" to the console
6. `Debug.Log("test-3");`

   - print "test-3" to the console
7. `yield return break;`

   - Here we tell the underlying Unity system to both: (1) suspend execution of this function (the `yield`) and (2) to not resume it later (the `break`). Do not go to step 8.
8. `} //end while(a)`

   - Because of step 7, we never return to the while loop conditional statement and never perform any additional actions.
9. `} //end function`

   - Function terminates

So to answer your question "test-1" will be printed exactly once...if both `a` and `b` are both true.

Comment: thank you , but Coroutines are to repeat some instructions until loop is false (here if statement is true) , so here we know that b is true then why Debug.Log("test-1"); wont be repeated more than once after waiting the 1 second ?

Comment: @MrZero No. See step 7. Its very clearly explained in my answer.

Comment: but why it didn't take this first (yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);) in consideration to repeat whats above of it ?

Comment: @MrZero Because that statement says "put this method on pause and ***return here.*** See step 4 in my explanation. It does not say "return to top of method" it says "return HERE and ONLY HERE." A yield instruction is not a loop instruction, its a pause.

Comment: if in place of (yield return break;) i had (yield return null;) the coroutine will keep repeating the code before that yield cause  -a- is true but whats the difference between this (yield return null;) that we may have and the code above be repeated and the (yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);) we have inside IF  statement?? i know WaitForSeconds(1f) is to wait some time but while the loop is true it will continue executing the code above it after that time ??

Comment: @MrZero No. `yield return null` will do the exact same thing, except that execution will resume *next frame* instead of *in one second.* See [this chart](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html): `yield null` and `yield WaitForSeconds` are adjacent in the execution sequence. If you want this to loop forever you ***must remove `yield break;`***

Comment: if they have the same role beside time thing, why yield WaitForSeconds didnt loop (Debug.Log("test-1");)  but  it moves  after 1 second to next lines of code ? is that cause its inside and IF statement maybe ? sorry for taking your time

Comment: @MrZero Because that's [what `WaitForSeconds` does](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html). It *waits for n seconds.*

Comment: it doesnt mean to repeat the code above it when while loop is true like what yield return null do  ?

Comment: @MrZero The `yield` instruction ***is not a loop.*** No `yield return x` for any `x` will ever make this code loop. None. Zero. Nada. That is not what that instruction does, it never has, and never will. `yield return null` will cause the execution to pause ***for one frame*** as I said in an earlier comment.

Comment: thanks after compiling and testing i found that like what u said yield doesn't mean like what i thought a pause point to repeat whats above it its a pause point to continue executing the code lines in next frame or after a determined time if WaitForSeconds object used